# Dropdown misaligned when rotate or change orientation (iPad)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

dropdown list is misaligned when I rotate the device. I want the dropdown list is align on the select tag. I used javascript to close or blur the dropdown list when rotate but the browser crashed. Is there a work around on this? Below is the code that I'm using for the orientation detection.

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var winWidth = $(window).width();

if(winWidth <= 768) {
   detectOrientation();
   window.onorientationchange = detectOrientation;
   function detectOrientation(){

      if (typeof window.onorientationchange != 'undefined'){
        if ( orientation == 0 ) {
            //Do Something In Portrait Mode

        }
        else if ( orientation == 90 ) {
            //Do Something In Landscape Mode

        }
        else if ( orientation == -90 ) {
            //Do Something In Landscape Mode

        }
        else if ( orientation == 180 ) {
            //Do Something In Portrait Mode

        }
    }
  }
} 

else {
  alert("not passed");
}
});
```